# BitmapData subclass and per-frame code

Tags: actionscript-3, events

I have a subclass of BitmapData intended to act as a source of random pixels for a Stage3D texture. To simplify matters, I would like to add a function that updates the noise on a per-frame basis before the frame is rendered to the back buffer. This can be accomplished by writing the constructor as follows

```
public function NoiseTexture(stage:Stage, size:int) {
    super(size, size, true, 0);
    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateNoise, false, 1);
}
```

and then setting the rendering function (also per-frame) to priority 0 to ensure that this code is executed first. In testing this, though, I noticed that when a NoiseTexture instance is set to null or reinstantiated the updateNoise function continues to be called (now twice in the case of reinstantiation) - makes sense, as the event listener is added to an object external to the class. I was wondering if there is a sneaky way to handle the removal of the event listener from within the class when this happens, or if I must handle that externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use weak listener, which is removed when the object is dereferenced. To do this, set `useWeakReference` parameter to true when adding the event listener.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateNoise, false, 1, true);
```

Comment: Stellar! Until recently I've just been using simple event handling - it's easy to miss some of those properties when you are used to ignoring them :)

Comment: Careful using weak references. It can cause unpredictable results since you're relying on scope change for it to be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good practice to create `dispose|clear` methods for classes, like a dealloc method in C language. And also you should use weak references as mentioned @Vesper.

```
//Some class
public function dispose():void{
    //clear references, stop timers, remove listeners
    stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateNoise);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that it is not removed immediately upon deallocation/reinstantiation when useWeakReference=true?

Comment: It will be removed on next Garbage collection cycle. It's very easy to test.

Comment: Gotcha. In this instance that shouldn't matter (all the listener does is flip a boolean), but I'll definitely keep that in mind for other applications. Thanks again, Nicolas.